# R Shiny adjust content to fit window size

Tags: r, shiny, tabs

In R shiny I would like to resize the content according to the window size without any scroll bars appearing.
I know that there are different places where the user can put in different commands for height but after testing out several options, I haven't managed to find the right one.

In my case this applies to the content inside a tabPanel.
There are two problems I would like solve:

---

**Tab with map and text underneath**:

Here I would like the map to take up all of the space that isn't occupied by the disclaimer underneath.

E.g.: 1. Window height: 1000 px, Map height: 950 px; Text height: 50 px ; 2. Resized  Window height: 800 px, Map height: 750 px; Text height: 50 px

---

**Tab with plot/image**:

Here I have a plot (specifically grid.arrange with 3 cols containing ggplots) and if the window gets too narrow the plot does adjust to the window size but it gets squished, pushing some of the text together and/or out of frame. To solve this I figured it would be a good idea to render it as an image before displaying it on the page. However, if the image width exceeds the page width, a scroll bar is added.

What I would need here is either a way to keep the plot ratio and sizes the same when resizing or a way to adjust the image width to never exceed the tab width.

---

Code:

```
# Map Tab
              tabPanel("Map", # add style and height command here?
                       
                       leafletOutput("map"), # add height inside here?
                       
                       #add fluidRow for each?
                      
                       Disclaimer_S
                       
                       
                       ), 
              
# Comparison Tab
              tabPanel("Comparison", style="overflow:auto", # add width command here?

                       plotOutput("complot"), # add width command here?

                       ),
```